# Call system package with Go on App Engine Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, go, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html) in a [Go](https://golang.org/) application thats running on [Google App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/). I can get this to run locally, when I point to a local instance of the FFmpeg binary using exec.Command()

```
cmd := exec.Command(
    "/Users/justin/Desktop/conversion/ffmpeg", // this won't work on a remote server
    "-i", "pipe:0",
    "-ac", "1",
    "-codec:a", "libmp3lame",
    "-b:a", "48k",
    "-ar", "24000",
    "-f", "mp3",
    "pipe:1",
  )

  cmd.Stdin = bytes.NewReader(synthResp.AudioContent)

  var output bytes.Buffer
  cmd.Stdout = &output
  err = cmd.Run()
```

Obviously, this won't work when I deploy the application, so I need a way to point to a hosted version of the FFmpeg binary. It seems `ffmpeg` is a [system package](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/reference/system-packages) for the go1.11 App Engine Standard environment.

**What are "System packages" and how do I use them?**
When I look for documentation, I find a lot of documentation on `apt-get`, and no documentation on how to use them, App Engine or otherwise. Do I need to install it, or should it already be part of the container(?) that App Engine is running?

Do I call it, like I'd call other executables? If so, that I'd expect this to work, but it doesn't

```
cmd := exec.Command(
    "ffmpeg", // <------ what should this be?
    "-i", "pipe:0",
    "-ac", "1",
    "-codec:a", "libmp3lame",
    "-b:a", "48k",
    "-ar", "24000",
    "-f", "mp3",
    "pipe:1",
  )

  cmd.Stdin = bytes.NewReader(synthResp.AudioContent)

  var output bytes.Buffer
  cmd.Stdout = &output
  err = cmd.Run()
```

Logging err, I see `exec: "ffmpeg": executable file not found in $PATH`

Comment: The [closest documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/functions/imagemagick/imagemagick.go) I can find shows how to use another Standard Package via Golang in that environment. What's confusing is the call `md := exec.Command("convert", "-", "-blur", "0x8", "-")` makes no reference it ImageMagik

Comment: The `convert` command is one of the main ImageMagik commands. The `ffmpeg` command is on  $PATH in the go113 environment and is probably available in go111. The path to the executable is `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`.  What error did you get when trying to run `ffmpeg`?

Comment: The start of the error I get is

`CRITICAL: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

goroutine 38 [running]:
google.golang.org/appengine/panic(0x16d11a0, 0x1e09b70)
 /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:522 +0x1b5
cloud.google.com/go/storage.(*ObjectHandle).validate(0x0, 0x17fa960, 0x18c01c0)`

The output is piped into a Google Cloud storage object. Looks like that's panicing because there's no output from the call to `ffmpeg`.

When I log the output from cmd;run() I see `exec: "ffmpeg": executable file not found in $PATH`

Comment: I deployed an app with this handler in runtime go113: `func h(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-h"); p, err := cmd.CombinedOutput(); fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v %s\n", err, p) }`.  The handler prints the ffmpeg help as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to question asked by @iLoveReflection I realize that the locally running version of the app will call the `ffmpeg` command, expecting it to be in a location pointed to by the standard $PATH environmental variable. I had thought App Engine would recognize the call to `ffmpeg` and use an executable it had installed in a custom location.

Moving the `ffmpeg` executable to `/usr/local/bin`, and ensuring $PATH included that directory fixed the issue.

Comment: The executable is installed in a standard location on App Engine. It's not necessary or possible to move the executable to /usr/local/bin.

Comment: True. I think I was unclear in my question. I could only get it to run *locally* when I used the full path. I wanted to move away from using the full path, and just use "ffmpeg" because a full path wouldn't work on a remote server. But calling just 'ffmpeg' locally wasn't working